# VBA code with multiple For loops running very slow

Tags: performance, vba, loops

my code is running very slow, is it the 2 For loops causing it?

Thanks

```
    For x = LBound(dataArray) To UBound(dataArray) 'define start and end of array, lower bound to upper bound
        For Each rngcell In Range("A:B") 'lookup each cell in row 1
            If dataArray(x) = rngcell.Value Then ' if cells in header row match with values in array
                rngcell.EntireColumn.Copy ' then copy whole column of data for that parameter
                Sheets(3).Select ' select sheet to paste data
                Range("A:B").End(xlUp).Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=x).Select 'select area to paste, paste in next column - no. x
                Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues ' paste
            End If
        Next rngcell ' next header row cell
    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: It's probably more so that you're looping through every cell in columns A and B.  You should limit the loop to just be the used range.  Also, it looks like you can get rid of the loops all together by just autofiltering and copying over the visible rows.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding Autofiltering, I know it can filter rows, but how would it filter columns?

Answer (score 1):

Just a few suggestions:

- Doing `.Select` causes Excel to update the UI, which is expensive. Try to calculate the target cell/range ONCE and use that to call PasteSpecial and not Selection.
- Selecting the Sheet(3) could be done before the loop, as it doesnt change.
- IF (!) max. ONE dataArray Element matches ONE rngcell.Value, you could abort the rest of the inner loop by using Exit For before the End If, saving the useless rest of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `Range(A:B)` which is definitely slowing your code down.
Excel will basically read every cell in that range according to your code.

That's 2 million cells.

Try to limit the range on the B by using something like `Replace(Range("B").End(Xldown).Address,"$B$","")`.